# DiscordJS (14.0) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')

Tags: javascript, if-statement, discord, discord.js, bots

I am new to JS (and DiscordJS) - I was hoping to figure out why this is crashing my bot.

The intention is to produce a 5% chance to reply to all users who have the specified role ID.

The bot turns on correctly, but as soon as anything is detected or changed in the server, it crashes with:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')

Any pointers or tips are greatly appreciated!

```
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  let args = message.content.trim().split(" ");
  if (message.author.roles.cache.has("641904594041045002")) {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.author.id === "95784650613456896") return;
    const responses = [
      "Reply1",
      "Reply2",
      "Reply3",
      "Reply4",
    ];
    const reply = responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length)];
    if (Math.random() < 0.05) {
      //0.50 = 50% chance

      message.reply(`${reply}`);
    }
  }
});
```

EDIT:
Changing   `if (message.author.roles.cache.has("641904594041045002")) {`
to
`if (message.member.roles.cache.has("641904594041045002")) {`
fixes the problem, until a user joins a voice channel - which causes the bot to crash again, with the same TypeError.

EDIT2:

```
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => { //now async
  let args = message.content.trim().split(" ");
  const member = await message.guild.members.fetch(message.author.id) //fetch author ID
  if(message.member.roles.cache.some(r=>["bois"].includes(r.name)) ); {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.author.id === "95784650613456896") return;
    const responses = [
  "Reply1",
  "Reply2",
  "Reply3",
  "Reply4",
    ];
    const reply = responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length)];
    if (Math.random() < 0.99) {
      //0.50 = 50% chance

      message.reply(`${reply}`);
    }
  }
});
```

This produces a different crash (when a user joins/leaves a voice call): *DiscordAPIError[10013]: Unknown User*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `message.author`, which returns a [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object that doesn't have the `roles` property, you should use `message.member` which returns a [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object instead:

```js
if (message.member.roles.cache.has("641904594041045002")) {
```

You might need to fetch the member like so:

```js
const member = await message.guild.members.fetch(message.author)
if (member.roles.cache.has("641904594041045002")) {
```

Comment: This seems to work now - but when a user joins a voice channel, the bot immediately crashes with the same ""TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'roles')"" 

(line 69 which contains "  if (message.member.roles.cache.has("641904594041045002")) {"

Comment: You might need to fetch it using the Guild#fetchMember function: see https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/2984

Comment: I see - How do I go about including the Fetch in this particular code? I'm really new to this.

Comment: No worries! Try using `const member = await message.guild.members.fetch(message.author.id)` and change the function from `(message) => {` to `async (message) => {`

Comment: Thank you! I tried this, but it is throwing a different error now. I've updated the post with "EDIT 2" for additional insight/info.

Comment: Hm, try doing `await message.guild.members.fetch(message.author)` instead

Comment: I think it works! Tested, and it didn't crash so far! I wish I could give you several upvotes <3

Comment: Nice! Thanks for your patience haha, I haven't used Discord.js in a while so my knowledge was a bit rusty